# Spark streaming doesnt identify application/octet-stream type in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, azure-blob-storage

I´m trying to stream a file from azure blob storage to Cassandra, however Spark doesn´t identify the application/octet-stream type. I tried these codes:

```
  val dstream: DStream[String] = ssc
    .fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](filePath, (path: Path) => path.getName().endsWith(pathEndsWith), true)
    .map(_._2.toString)
```

Without filter:

```
  val dstream: DStream[String] = ssc
    .fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](filePath)
    .map(_._2.toString)
```

As Sequence file:

```
  val dstream: DStream[String] = ssc
    .fileStream[Text, Text, SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat](filePath)
    .map(_._2.toString)
```

Comment: Ivan, Do you get any specific errors or exceptions ? It would be helpful for the community to identify the specific issue.

Comment: There is no exception in this case, The file is identified in the logs, however, when you try to access the file information it´s simply empty.